# consuming SSRS or SSRS Web service in JQuery

Tags: jquery, reporting-services

I wan to consume SSRS reports with JQuery and I have to use JQuery UI components like table graph etc. I am just wondering how to achieve this with JQuery.
I don’t wanna report viewer control. Is this possible to use JQuery with SSRS Web Service and use all features of JQuery UI like table and Chart and effects etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can run your report directly by hitting the URL containing a parameter to specify the return type.  From this you can grab it in XML or HTML format, e.g.

```
http://zorro/ReportServer/?%2fEdgewoodLab%2fzPass_Params_with_HTML&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=HTML
```

You'll potentially need to write some functions in your client to handle the response and potentially parse it into a more useable format but this will at least allow you to grab your report + data via URL.

Check out [this article](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1336/pass-parameters-and-options-with-a-url-in-sql-reporting-services/) to find out how to pass parameters and retrieve your report via URL.

Alternatively, you can [use the Data Feed functionality of SSRS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff519563.aspx), which provides ATOM feeds of report data.  This tends to behave more consistently than the XML or HTML output, but will require more work to parse.  However, there's a chance you could get a jQuery plugin to help with this.

Check out [this post](http://thinknook.com/convert-ssrs-graphs-to-highcharts-graphs-2012-01-21/), which uses the ATOM Data Feed to grab a report and render it using the HighCharts JS plugin.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time you put to reply. Example explained to use JQuery char from SSRS char, is it possible to use just SSRS report DATASET to build JQuery graph/Table? As I am new to JQuery, can I use the same technique you mentioned adove with JQuery Table, if I render my report from URL as HTML table and then using JQuery to enhance the user interface?